# nodemon command not found in git bash

Tags: node.js, git-bash, nodemon

I am trying to run my node.js app in Git bash terminal. It worked before every time I type `nodemon server.js`. Recently, I upgrated my node.js and npm. If I try to run my app on Git Bash again, an error of

```
C:\Users\PC\AppData\Roaming\npm/node_modules/node/bin/node: line 1: This: command not found
```

Shows up.

I tried uninstalling and installing nodemon with `npm install -g nodemon`, and reinstalled git, the error still persists. Although, nodemon works fine on windows cmd terminal.

It would be nice to make it work on Git Bash terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Also facing the same issue! But I found a way around using  `npx nodemon script.js`

Although I found the problem. Git bash is trying to execute nodemon from this directory: `C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm/node_modules/node/bin/node`

But in this path nodemon doesn't exist.

The path should be `C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nodemon`

Answer (score 0):

it actually comes down to the place you installed the Nodemon tool.
most people will install it in their working directory but i found that this way is not a safe bet. you should install it in the root directory as it will not cause trouble once you try to use it in another project.